# Trojaned version of file "egrep" detected by OSSEC HIDS

Tags: antivirus, malware, trojan, ossec

I have installed the latest stable version of [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/?page_id=19) (2.8.1), and I have also enabled email notifications and today I got this alert through email:

```
OSSEC HIDS Notification.
2015 Apr 03 17:40:26

Received From: Bath-Towel->rootcheck
Rule: 510 fired (level 7) -> "Host-based anomaly detection event (rootcheck)."
Portion of the log(s):

Trojaned version of file '/bin/egrep' detected. Signature used: 'bash|^/bin/sh|file\.h|proc\.h|/dev/|^/bin/.*sh' (Generic).



 --END OF NOTIFICATION
```

Is this something to worry about, and if so then what should I do about it?

**Information Update:**

This is the contents of the file `/bin/egrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep=grep
case $0 in
  */*)
    dir=${0%/*}
    if test -x "$dir/grep"; then
      PATH=$dir:$PATH
      grep=grep
    fi;;
esac
exec $grep -E "$@"
```

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: `egrep` should be a shell script that ultimately runs `grep -E`. Check what's inside `/bin/egrep`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho: Ok, I have updated my question with the contents, so is there anything to actually worried about, if not then what did the alert by OSSEC HIDS mean?

Comment: Read the OSSEC documentation. From looking at the message, it probably combined the file being in /bin with the file contents matching the pattern 'bash|^/bin/sh|file\.h|proc\.h|/dev/|^/bin/.*sh'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have OSSEC installed on some 14.04 servers, but I never got such notification.

It turns out that until Ubuntu 14.04 `/bin/egrep` is an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, but in 14.10 and later it is a shell script. Probably OSSEC was not updated yet to reflect this change.